# Mysql live database migration/conversion

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably any team will encounter at some point so I'm counting on experience other guys had.

We are in a process of migrating old MySQL database to a new database with structure changed quite a bit. Some tables were split into multiple smaller tables, some data was joined from multiple smaller to one larger table.

We ran a test and it takes a few hours to migrate database to a new form. The problem is, the old database is our production database, changes every minute. We cannot have a few hours downtime.

What approach do you think would be ok in such a situation?

Let's say you have table called "users" with 1M rows. It's being changed every second. Some fields are updated, some rows are added and some rows are deleted. That's the problem why we cannot make a snapshot at certain point of time because after the migration is done, we would have 3 hours of data unsynced.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I've used in the past was to use [replication.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

We created a replication scheme between the old production database and a slave which was used for the data migration. When we started the migration, we switched off the replication temporarily, and used the slave database as the data source for the migration; the old production system remained operational.

Once the migration script had completed, and our consistency checks had run, we re-enabled replication from the old production system to the replicated slave. Once the replication had completed, we hung up the "down for maintenance" sign on production, re-ran the data migration scripts and consistency checks, pointed the system to the new database, and took down the "down for maintenance" sign.

There was downtime, but it was minutes, rather than hours.

This does depend on your database schema to make it easy to identify changed/new data.

If your schema does not lend itself to easy querying to find new or changed records, and you don't want to add new columns to keep track of this, the easiest solution is to create separate tables to keep track of the migration status.

For instance:

```
TABLE: USERS (your normal, replicated table)
----------------------
USER_ID
NAME
ADDRESS
.....


TABLE: USERS_STATUS (keeps track of changes, only exists on the "slave")
-----------------
USER_ID
STATUS
DATE
```

You populate this table via a trigger on the USERS table for insert, delete and update - for each of those actions, you set a separate status.

This allows you to quickly find all records that changed since you ran your first migration script, and only migrate those records.

Because you're not modifying your production environment, and the triggers only fire on the "slave" environment, you shouldn't introduce any performance or instability problems on the production environment.

Comment: The key point here is the "This does depend on your database schema to make it easy to identify changed/new data.". If you had a few million records in a table it would take some time to go through all the records and see changed data. But this has pointed me in the right direction. Maybe we could use the slave relay log files somehow after we switch the replication back on.

Comment: See the edit - there are ways of identifying changed data, but this is very dependent on the original schema - if you have no primary keys, it gets pretty tricky...

Comment: Yeah, this is a great solution - at least for my case. Even if there are no primary keys we could add them but in general there are. something like this did come to my mind but on a live db. Introduction of replication and slave is great. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There's one approach I used once and that should work for you too, however you'll need to do modify your production datasets for that. Just briefly:

1. Add a new column named "migrated" (or so) to every table you want to migrate. Give it a boolean type. Set it to 0 by default.
2. When your migration script runs it has to set this flag to 1 for every entry that has been migrated to the new db. All entries that are already "1" have to be ignored. That way you won't run into synchronization issues.

That way you can run the migration script as often as you like.

You will have a downtime, but it will be just a minimal one because during that downtime you only have to migrate a few datasets (practically the last "delta" between the last run of the migration script and now).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have considered the same approach but the problem is - this is ok only for tables which add new rows. How do I know if rows were deleted or there was a change somewhere in the middle of the dataset?

Comment: To track changes in datasets I usually have a versioning-column in every dataset. On every change (UPDATE) this value gets incremented. You can easily compare this data between production and migration database. For deleted rows I'm afraid you will have to do some comparison during the downtime. based on the PKs it shouldn't take too long to figure out the rows that have been deleted in production and delete them on the migrated DB as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you run the new database in parallel with the current one? That way you can later migrate the old data from your old db to your new one and your "live" situation will already have been captured on the new one.

What I mean is: when you write something to the old db, you will also have to write the data to the new one.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is something we did consider, but the problem is that in some cases we have literally hundreds of places from where one table is being changed so it would take too much time and probably bugs to do it this way. In a more organized code, I do think this would be a viable solution.